# After a reboot, first debug session requires me to grant permissions to Apple Developer Tools

Tags: xcode4

Unfortunately, I often find I need to reboot to wipe some unhealthy Xcode state. Here is my issue: after a reboot, and finally being able to restart Xcode 4.1.1 (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468218)), the first time I try to run with debug, I get a Lion prompt window requiring me to grant Apple Developer Tools permission to take control of another process.

[image]

Is this a known issue, or something specific to my installation? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Google hit might be helpful: http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2011/Oct/msg00191.html  - Assuming you've already done the usual Disk Utility "repair permissions" thing.

Comment: @WarrenP : this user is admin on the box. However i dont know the Disk Utility 'Repair permissions' thingie. Will go hunt.

Comment: @WarrenP : nope, disk utility 'repair permissions' did not remove the condition.

Comment: I'm guessing you should go to the Apple dev forums and ask about Lion bugs with XCode 4.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months of looking for this:

as administrator do:

/usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity -enable

/usr/sbin/dseditgroup -o edit -t group -a staff _developer