# Xcode 4.1.1 : does not index a newly added obj-c file unless i restart Xcode

Tags: xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

In a current project (480 source files), whenever i add a new module, i cant seem to have the .h and .m files indexed, so i 'code blind'. It compiles fine though. In order to get the index refreshed i MUST quit and restart Xcode (with all the vagaries associated with it , see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468218/xcode-4-1-1-taking-very-large-amounts-of-memory-on-startup-up-to-5-4-gb).

Is there a way (without the restart) to force Xcode to reindex the project. Note: cleaning, deleting derived data, and rebuilding do not work.

Comment: Update to Xcode 4.2. There's no reason not to, or is there?

Comment: well, other than every update has been a walk through hell so far, none whatsoever. Also, not certain if ARC is 'mandotary' dogma, ie whether i will have to go through 480 modules to turn it off :). Finally, each version of Xcode has been a surprise pack : old bugs go away, some get worse, and new ones appear. I need to get through next 2 months, then i may consider it ... actually have planned the update for our next product. But till then, i'd rather avoid any forklift if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 4.3 solves this, although it has its own quirks with regards to indexing ... indexes 'all' 'all the time'... Fed up, i switched to AppCode.